# How to get the details of all statements executed under warehouse for previous month

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Part#1
we have a warehouse of size small,How do i know what is the maximum load that a warehouse  can bear? ,in otherwards how do i check the utilization of warehouse against its maximum capacity ?

Part#2
 we see almost majority of the queries with status as "Running" in "warehouse over load time" bar graph   none of them are in status Queued,I feel its a good sign.But i see some time in the month of march the load graph is at 1.9(running status).I like to to analyse that workload.
we have option in  history tab to filter queries based on the warehouse to know the  details of statements executed under specific warehouse in web ui.I am looking for the alternative from SQL where in i can filter the details for  one specific day in the month of march.
(or)
do we have an option in history tab web ui so that i can jump to specific day rather than keep clicking "continue search "button  at the bottom?
I am in the process identifying the warehouse that are overused/underused.Can someone please help me the industry proven approach to do this exercise.

How to identify the whether the warehouse is being used efficiently or its under used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part #1** : Identify whether your warehouse has been utilized optimally

To be honest this would be little bit tricky , first identify the problem area from  query_history, then move to that time frame to check the Utilization from below tables using 'Warehouse' and 'date' in the where clause.

```
select * from "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."WAREHOUSE_METERING_HISTORY"
select * from "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."WAREHOUSE_LOAD_HISTORY"
```

**#Part 2** : How to analyse queries of a specific month

You can update below query as per your need (I drafted just to validate). 
This would be a complete query for your utilization analysis.

```
SELECT
TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('minute', query_history.START_TIME ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS 
"query_history.start_time",
query_history.QUERY_TEXT  AS "query_history.query_text",
query_history.QUERY_TYPE  AS "query_history.query_type",
query_history.WAREHOUSE_NAME  AS "query_history.warehouse_name",
query_history.WAREHOUSE_SIZE  AS "query_history.warehouse_size",
query_history.USER_NAME  AS "query_history.user_name",
query_history.EXECUTION_TIME  AS "query_history.execution_time"
FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY  AS query_history
WHERE MONTH(query_history.START_TIME) ='3'
--(query_history.EXECUTION_STATUS = 'SUCCESS') 
--AND (query_history.WAREHOUSE_SIZE != '0')
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('minute', query_history.START_TIME ),2,3,4,5,6,7
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Thanks,

Palash Chatterjee

Comment: Sure will check this,Any thoughts on "How to identify the whether the warehouse is being used efficiently or its under used?"

Comment: there is a really good snowflake article available on the warehouse utilization  https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Understanding-Your-Snowflake-Utilization-Part-1-Warehouse-Profiling

Comment: I read this article some time back,its  very good article in the series of  total 3 posts of profiling .In my case I Am not seeing much of AVG_QUEUE_LOAD in my environment,does that means the warehouse are used optimally ? Higher values of ratio   avg(AVG_RUNNING) / avg(credits_used) * 100    tells the warehouse is being used efficiently ?is that is the way to understand?

Comment: Found this in the snowflakes documentation  "the total query load was less than 1 for substantial periods of time, the warehouse use is inefficient. You might consider any of the following actions:

Decrease the warehouse size. Note that decreasing the warehouse size generally increases the query execution time.

For a multi-cluster warehouse, decrease the MIN_CLUSTER_COUNT parameter value.'

Comment: If you are not seeing much AVG_QUEUE_LOAD , that could also mean your warehouse might be under utilized, you need to validate your AVG_RUNNING  as well.  In a simple way if warehouse runs more and then it is queuing, you should check  either increasing the size or distributing the jobs to other warehouse or work on the cluster. Before taking that call as you mentioned check for the ratio if  credit used is more also the running is more than warehouse is efficiently utilized.  if the running is less and credit is more than reduce the warehouse auto-suspend and do the analysis again

Comment: for warehouse size I would suggest "start with minimal " and track the queuing. Ideal option would be start with minimum size and minimum auto suspend and increase these parameter gradually based on load and queuing. Utilization optimization check must be bottom up pattern rather top down

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214006/discussion-between-palash-chatterjee-and-user13492282).